# Cannot compile Myriad Pro with FontPro

Tags: fonts

My goal is to use Myriad Pro (+ MdSymbol) as math fonts.

Currently, I am using a setup based on `mathspec`, but I am not happy with the glyph bounds.
For example, the `f` in `$f(x)$` collides with the opening bracket, and always using `$"f(x)$` is kind of annoying.

I saw that there is the tool FontPro (https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) that compiles a MyriadPro package.
However, trying to build the package results in

```
! \install... error:
        Font/MTX file MyriadPro-BoldIt-integral not found.
```

after some time. (Earlier parts of the script for the regular and italic font seem to succeed.)
I am trying to build using TeXLive 2020 and Debian Buster WSL on Windows.

I am unsure whether the problem is the build environment or my input files (the `.otf` files for Myriad Pro).
Unfortunately, FontPro does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Has anyone recently succeeded in building a font with FontPro?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the font for `pdflatex`? Simply put the otf-files into your systems font directory and then load the files with `unicode-math` and run the document with `lualatex`

Comment: I do not necessarily want to convert for `pdflatex`. (Currently I am using `xelatex`). If I simply load the font with `unicode-math`, I will not get a good result, since the font has no native math support. FontPro seems to have some additional kerning tables that hopefully will solve some of the problems that my current setup has.

Comment: By the way: The MyriadPro package indeed solves all the problems that using MyriadPro + `mathspec`/`unicode-math` + `xetex` has. With this combination, the kerning / glyph bounds in things like `$f(x)$` or `$f^i$` is just terrible. With the MyriadPro package, it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the problem was the capitalization in the names of the font files.

Good: `MyriadPro-Bold.otf`

Bad: `MyriadPro-BOLDIT.OTF`

Comment: Naming problem happens if you are using `MacOS`, but it is not an issue in `Windows`

Comment: As I wrote, I am using WSL, the linux subsystem for Win10, which cares about capitalization in file names.